# switch statements

Tags: java, switch-statement

The problem is to write the paragraph 5 different times. Each paragraph has a different cage number and corresponding animal. So cage 1 has a lion and cage 2 has a tiger. The problem is I don't know how to combine both the cage number the different corresponding animal in the same  paragraph.

I don't know how to enter the switch statement in the second line of the paragraph. I tried writing println("This cage holds a " + i); but Eclipse gave me an error. How do i incorporate both variables n and i in the same paragraph at the same time?

```
import acm.program.*;

public class ZooAnimals extends ConsoleProgram {
    private static final int START = 1; 

    public void run(){
        for (int n = START; n <=5; n++ ) {
             println("This animal is in cage" + n);
             println("This cage holds a " );  <---- type of animal goes in here. 
             println("Wild animals are very dangerous.");
        }       

        for(int i = START; i<=5; i++) {
              switch(i) { 
                   case 1: println("lion");
                   case 2: println("tiger");
                   case 3: println("elephant");
                   case 4: println("snakes");
                   case 5: println("hippo");
              }                   
        } 

    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error? and you have not used break; after each case!!

Comment: oops. I did add the breaks in my code for my homework. I forgot to add them here. If i try to write println("This cage holds a" + i); Eclipse gives me a "i cannot be resolved to a variable" error.

Comment: ok just save your program after each edit. eclipse doesn't remove error messages unless it is saved !!

Comment: Do you have to use a switch statement? This sounds like the sort of thing where a `Map<Integer, String>` would be appropriate.

Comment: @edd I have to use the things that I've learned so far. Some of the suggestions have been to use arrays but that has not been covered in my book so far. I've learned about..for..while...if..and switch.

Comment: @JessicaM. That's a perfectly valid reason then. I was just wanting to know before providing a `Map` answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would write a small method like so:

```
public String getAnimal(int cage)
{
     switch(cage) { 
           case 1: return "lion";
           case 2: return "tiger";
           case 3: return "elephant";
           case 4: return "snakes";
           case 5: return "hippo";
           default: return "Animal Not Found!";
           }    

}
```

I would then replace this code:

```
for (int n = START; n <=5; n++ ) {
  println("This animal is in cage" + n);
  println("This cage holds a " );     <-----------type of animal goes in here. 
  println("Wild animals are very dangerous.");
             }
```

with this:

```
for (int n = START; n <=5; n++ ) {
  println("This animal is in cage" + n);
  println("This cage holds a " + getAnimal(n));     <-----------type of animal goes in here. 
  println("Wild animals are very dangerous.");
             }
```

Comment: I think you mean  println("This cage holds a " getAnimal(n));

Comment: @BhavikShah: Yes you are correct, sorry my bad. It should be fixed now.

Comment: Is this faster than using a HashMap?

Comment: @Roger: I do not think so. In the best scenario the `switch` will yield the correct result in 1 step while if not found, it will yield the result in 6 steps. A `HashMap` always requires 1 step to access it's value.

Answer (score 1):

I would use an array

```
public class ZooAnimals extends ConsoleProgram {
    String[] animals = "none,lion,tiger,elephant,snake,hippo".split(",");

    public void run() {
        for (int n = START; n < animals.length; n++) {
            println("This animal is in cage" + n);
            println("This cage holds a " + animals[n]);
            println("Wild animals are very dangerous.");
        }

        for (int i = START; i < animals.length; i++) {
             println(animals[i]);
        }
```

Comment: thanks. I think arrays are covered in the later chapters so i have not learned about them so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to print i as you asked about you would get the sentence: 'This cage holds a 1'.  I suspect this is not what you are after.  Instead, create a variable to hold the name of the animal and assign its value in your switch statement.  After that you can do your println statement.

This looks to me like a homework assignment, so I'll leave you to figure out how to implement that exactly :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do this

```
 import acm.program.*;

public class ZooAnimals extends ConsoleProgram {

public void run(){

for (int n = START; n <=5; n++ ) {
  println("This animal is in cage" + n);
  println("This cage holds a " );     <-----------type of animal goes in here. 

           switch(n) { 
           case 1: println("lion");break;
           case 2: println("tiger");break;
           case 3: println("elephant");break;
           case 4: println("snakes");break;
           case 5: println("hippo");break;
               }                   

println("Wild animals are very dangerous.");
              }

private static final int START = 1;
```

}

Comment: For formatting's sake, I would replace `println("This cage holds a " )` with a `print...`. This will make sure that the sentence and the animal name appear on a continuous line.

Answer (score 0):

delete second for cycle, in switch use n instead of i and add break into each branch of switch.

Even best would be to create array containing names of animals in correct order and than just using "n" as index to get name of correct animal

Answer (score 0):

You should use `print` method instead of `println`. See the line before `switch`.

and, use `break` when using switch.

```
for (int n = START; n <=5; n++ ) 
{   
    println("This animal is in cage" + n);   
    print("This cage holds a " );

    switch(n) 
    {             
        case 1: println("lion"); break;        
        case 2: println("tiger"); break;            
        case 3: println("elephant");  break;           
        case 4: println("snakes");  break;           
        case 5: println("hippo");  break;
        default: println("unknown"); break; // good practice to add default case.
    }
}

println("Wild animals are very dangerous.");
```

Comment: Thanks. Another user suggested the same thing. I'll definitely try that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing instead swicth use if else and call function in it and return value from there

```
 for(int n = START;n<=5;n++){                     
        String animal=type();
        println("This animal is in cage" + n);
        println("This cage holds a "+animal);     <-----------type of animal goes in here. 
        println("Wild animals are very dangerous.");
 }

 for(int i = START; i<=5; i++) {
       switch(i) { 
           if(i==1){
                String type()
                    return "tiger";
           }else if(i==2){
                  String type()
                    return "lion"; 
           }

       }                   
  }
```

I hope this will...n yes it can be lot more better than this solution but for now this should work rest u can modify.
Good Luck

Comment: This answer will not work. It is syntactically incorrect, and kind of a mess right now. First you need to have a `curly braces` around your methods, even it is of single line. Second, you cannot define a method inside another method. In my opinion, this answer will just make the Original code more worse.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int n = START; n <=5; n++ ) {
  println("This animal is in cage" + n);
  println("This cage holds a " );     <-----------type of animal goes in here. 

       switch(n) { 
       case 1: println("lion");
       case 2: println("tiger");
       case 3: println("elephant");
       case 4: println("snakes");
       case 5: println("hippo");
       }                  

  println("Wild animals are very dangerous.");
```

}

I am not sure i have understood your question correctly. does the above code helps you ?

Comment: yes I'm trying to tryout all the suggested answers to see if it works for my problem. Thanks.